# How can I create a foreign key between 2 existing tables with matching columns in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, foreign-keys

I am dealing with some excel files that I need to find the 'differences' between. I started by creating 2 SQLite tables with them, programatically. There are two files that have the same columns, and have matching rows. The problem is that the rows are not necessarily in order, and there is no one key column that could match the rows. There are, however, four columns that I can join on at the same time.

My current solution to find the differences between the two tables is this query:

```sql
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, etc FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2
    WHERE table2.`SID` = table1.`SID`
    AND table2.`BID` = table1.`BID`
    AND table2.`OID` = table1.`OID`
    AND table2.`LID` = table1.`LID`);
```

I'd like the result to be the fields from table1 AND the fields from table2 for each record, so I end up with double the columns.

| field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi |
| jkl | mno | pqr |

| field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | AAA |
| jkl | mno | pqr |

to one table with all columns showing only differing rows:

| t1_field1 | t1_field2 | t1_field3 | t2_field1 | t2_field2 | t2_field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | abc | def | AAA |

<strike>I think a better approach than some complex sql is to retroactively create a foreign key for both of the tables so that making a query like that would be much simpler.</strike>

Remember that I create these tables and insert data programatically, so if the solution lies during the creation, I can still implement your suggestions.

**EDIT:**  As @marcos pointed out, a foreign key would be impossible due to the matching row not being guaranteed to exist. A compound join sounds like a good path.

My intention is to find any differences at all, including the deletion of a row, from table1 to table2. I don't need the differences from 2 to 1.

This query @marcos recommended (minus the t2 - t1 union) almost works perfectly:

```sql
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, ..., t2.field1, t2.field2
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON  t1.SID = t2.SID
    AND t1.BID = t2.BID
    AND t1.OID = t2.OID
    AND t1.LID = t2.LID
WHERE t2.SID IS NULL
```

returning something like:

| t1_field1 | t1_field2 | t1_field3 | t2_field1 | t2_field2 | t2_field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | --- | --- | --- |

But unfortunately the columns from table2 do not populate. I'm also unsure of how the `WHERE t2.SID IS NULL` works here, since SID is not a unique key.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Desired output returns only one record because it has different data in Field3? How many fields do you need to do this comparison on? Maybe use OR operator: `SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON <your 4 field joins> WHERE T1.F5<>T2.F5 OR T1.F6<>T2.F6 OR etc.`????

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want all the lines in table1 that does not match table2 plus all the lines in table2 that does not match t1.

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, ..., t2.field1, t2.field2
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON  t1.SID = t2.SID
    AND t1.BID = t2.BID
    AND t1.OID = t2.OID
    AND t1.LID = t2.LID
WHERE t2.SID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, ..., t2.field1, t2.field2
FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON  t1.SID = t2.SID
    AND t1.BID = t2.BID
    AND t1.OID = t2.OID
    AND t1.LID = t2.LID
WHERE t1.SID IS NULL
```

Create an index on those four columns (SID, BID, OID and LID) to improve performance.

Foreign key is not possible, because they enforce that the data on one table is present in another table. You will get a fk constraint error if you try to create one.

Comment: Might add a calculated field in each SELECT to indicate source table: `"T1" AS Src`, then for table2 just `"T2"`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @June7 ! This query unfortunately only populates one tables's fields. I end up having rows with either the selected columns from table1 OR the selected columns for table2. What do you think I should try to fix this?

Comment: Suggested answer is not mine. Edit your question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Instead of UNION, could try a compound join with the 4 fields.

Comment: @June7 my bad, but thank you for the tips regardless. I did edit my question to have some idea of what I'm looking for. What do you think is going wrong here @marcos?

Comment: Sample data shows only 2 fields with data common to both tables for both sample records. If those two fields can provide unique identifier then compound join on only those two. Point is, there must be a field (or fields) that can be used as unique link between tables for ALL records. If you want to generate a single field record identifier in both tables when records are created, that would be an approach but as has been pointed out, synchronizing this value will not be simple. Just don't know enough about your data and process.

Comment: Then the UNION with SELECT JOIN should work.

Comment: @June7 I didn't want to make the sample data too long, but there are still 4 columns not shown that can provide the unique link. The union select, as I understand, looks for differences from t1 to t2, then unions that with the differences from t2 to t1. I only need the first part, t1 to t2. Furthermore, even without the second half of the query, the result does not show data from both tables on a single row, as my edit shows. Is there something I am not understanding?